# Accessing properties of an object within a class

Tags: c#

I have a class Car, which has a property Owner. Owner has two properties: FirstName and LastName

In my unit testing shown below, I can't get access to the two name fields,

"The name "owner" does not exist in the current context"

```cs
namespace CodeExcercise
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Test()
        {
            var cars = new List<Car>()
            {
                new Car() { owner.Firstname = "Brian", Lastname = "Badonde", Cost = 5, Registered = DateTime.Now},

            };

            new PrintMethod().PrintReport(cars, "CR.csv");
            var outPut = File.ReadAllLines("CR.csv");
            Assert.AreEqual(1, outPut.Count());
        }
    }

    public class Owner
    {
        public string Firstname;
        public string Lastname;
    }

    public class Car
    {
        public Owner owner;
        public double Cost;
        public DateTime Registered;     
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax you're using to set the `owner` properties here is incorrect:

```
new Car() { owner.Firstname = "Brian", Lastname = "Badonde", Cost = 5, Registered = DateTime.Now}
```

You'd create the `Owner` object with the same syntax as creating the `Car` object.  For example:

```
new Car()
{
    owner = new Owner()
    {
        Firstname = "Brian",
        Lastname = "Badonde"
    },
    Cost = 5,
    Registered = DateTime.Now
}
```

You can nest this as much as you like, each individual object creation is its own operation.

Comment: Oh it's so simple, I'm new to C#, thanks! perfect answer

Answer (score 3):

You have to create the new `Owner` object:

```
new Car
{
    owner = new Owner { Firstname = "Brian", Lastname = "Badonde" },
    Cost = 5,
    Registered = DateTime.Now
};
```

Comment: Oh it's so simple, I'm new to C#, thanks! perfect answer

Answer (score 3):

> I have a class Car, which has a property Owner. Owner has two properties: FirstName and LastName

I think what you mean to say is

> I have a car class, and I want to assign the Owner as an inline initializer.

in which case you have to create the type of the property and use the same inline initializer to set it's properties:

```
new Car
{
  Cost = 5,
  Registered = DateTime.Now,
  Owner = new Owner 
  { 
    Firstname = "Brian", 
    Lastname = "Badonde" 
  },
}
```

I've used an upper case property name because Microsoft Guidelines recommend all properties start with an upper case character.